# Posture for meditation

Tags: meditation, vipassana, meditation-posture

Is cross-legged sitting better than chair sitting for meditation. If yes why ?

What is the reason to keep ur back straight during meditation?

Answer (score 1):

> Is cross-legged sitting better than chair sitting for meditation. If yes why ?

For a beginner, more important to be relaxed and comfortable, and chair is fine.
For more advanced, the energy flows better, jhana battery charges faster, if you can sit comfortably in cross leg posture.

> What is the reason to keep ur back straight during meditation?

better energy flow and jhana battery charging.
If you stick with long term with meditation, you'll be able to verify for yourself.

Comment: what is jhana battery?

Comment: https://lucid24.org/sted/8aam/8samadhi/index.html

Comment: what happens if you don't eat, don't sleep? If you don't charge your jhana battery, meditation is going to be like that. no energy, no force, no power.

Answer (score 1):

> Is cross-legged sitting better than chair sitting for meditation. If yes why ?
>
> What is the reason to keep ur back straight during meditation?

No, if the leg lies on each other, but Yes, if each leg is on the floor.

The point is the weight and muscular.

The best balance of entire body weight is on laying-on-the-floor-legs sitting with straight back bones sitting (easier by the buttocks support, pillow, etc.)

It's good in both short and long term.

I've record this to explain what it looks like. I try to find the English version of this but it's not found.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFVwYgk5E4Y

Answer (score 0):

Keep your back straight so you realize you are too fat! Obviously it’s not the case for ppl with back problems but generally speaking a straight back is a straight line to heaven